# Sharepoint folder allow upload to but view only yours

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am looking to find appropriate settings that would allow a SharePoint folder to permit document upload to a set up of users but once uploaded, those users can see only their documents and not ones from others.

I have tried the manage-access-advanced permissions and this would not give me what was intended.

I saw elsewhere that this was a possibility but could not achieve it; any pointers would be appreciated.

I am using SharePoint from office-365.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go to site sttings > view and set the filter:

```
Created By is equal to [Me]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you; I was also able to find it in filter options.